# Go tool unable to find binary. go tool: no such tool "vet"

Tags: go

I'm running golang in a docker container. And 'go tool' is unable to find 'vet'. Could you give me ideas on how to debug this?

I've used the Dockerfile for 1.5 as a template. https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/51d6eacd41fe80d41105142b9ad32f575082970f/1.5/Dockerfile

```
ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.5.1
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL https://golang.org/dl/go$GOLANG_VERSION.linux-        amd64.tar.gz
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_SHA1 46eecd290d8803887dec718c691cc243f2175fe0

RUN curl -fsSL "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL" -o golang.tar.gz \
&& echo "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_SHA1  golang.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c - \
&& tar -C /usr/local -xzf golang.tar.gz \
&& rm golang.tar.gz

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```

However, when I install govet with

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
```

and try

```
bash-4.3# go tool vet
go tool: no such tool "vet"
```

I have the following go environment set up:

```
$PATH includes $GOPATH/bin /usr/lib/go/bin:/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

bash# go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
bash# ls $GOPATH/bin
fgt               go-junit-report   godep             golint            mt-content-blogs  vet   
bash# ls $GOROOT/bin/
go     gofmt
```

**The crux of the issue is that go tools does not list vet, even after installing it with `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet`**

```
bash# go tool
addr2line
api
asm
cgo
compile
dist
doc
fix
link
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
trace
yacc
```

Comment: It's `go vet`, not `go tool vet`.

Comment: It's exactly the same.
    bash-4.3# go vet
    go tool: no such tool "vet"

Comment: @P.C: Your use of `echo` is pointless. You are showing what you think Go is looking at. To find out what Go is actually looking at post the output from `go env`.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. I get a similar output.

    bash-4.3# go env
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN=""
    GOEXE=""
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="linux"
    GOOS="linux"
    GOPATH="/go"
    GORACE=""
    GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
    GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
    CC="gcc"
    GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
    CXX="g++"
    CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: @PC: The output of `go env` is good. As expected, the `vet` program is in `$GOPATH/bin` (`/go/bin`). Post the output of the `$PATH` command. With `/go/bin` in your `$PATH`, run `go vet` on a package or `go tool vet` on files or a directory. See [Command vet](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet).

Comment: @Ainar-G: `go vet` or `go tool vet`: [Command vet](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet).

Comment: @P.C:  Post the full list. Post the output ot `$PATH`. I get `$ go tool
addr2line
api
asm
cgo
compile
cover
dist
doc
fix
link
newlink
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
trace
vet
yacc
$`

Comment: Added it to the information dump. I can see `vet` in the $GOPATH/bin but `go tool` doesn't list it.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: starting Go 1.12 (February 2019, 3.5 years later), `go tool vet` won't be available at all. Only `go vet`.

See [go 1.12 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#vet):

> The `go vet` command has been rewritten to serve as the base for a range of different source code analysis tools. See the [`golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis) package for details.
>
> **A side-effect is that `go tool vet` is no longer supported**.
>   External tools that use `go tool vet` must be changed to use `go vet`.
>   Using `go vet` instead of `go tool vet` should work with all supported versions of Go.
>
> As part of this change, the experimental `-shadow` option is no longer available with `go vet`.
>   Checking for variable shadowing may now be done using:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shadow/cmd/shadow
go vet -vettool=$(which shadow)
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue. It appears that I had missed installing go tools on the base docker image that I was using.

```
RUN apk --update-cache --allow-untrusted \
--repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ \
--arch=x86_64 add \
go=${GOLANG_VERSION}-r3 \
go-tools=${GOLANG_VERSION}-r3 \
git \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
&& mkdir -p /go/src /go/bin \
&& chmod -R 777 /go
```